# JSF 2.0 Login + set User Principals

Tags: servlets, jsf-2, authentication

I am trying to use a jsf 2.0 form to authenticate a user.
Also I want to create UserPrincipals.
I thought with the HttpServletRequest.login method I can create a new UserPrincipal.
http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html

What I did is:

Formular:

```
    <h:form>
        <h:outputLabel value="Name" for="name"/>
        <h:inputText id="name" value="#{userMng.user.name }"/>
        <br/>
        <h:outputLabel value="Passwort" for="pw"/>
        <h:inputSecret id="pw" value="#{userMng.user.password }"/>
        <br/>
        <h:commandButton type="submit" value="Submit" action="#{ userMng.login }"/>
    </h:form>
```

UserMng (sessionscoped):
login method:

```
public String login() {
        String ret = "error";
        if (user.getName().equals("test") && user.getPassword().equals("test") ) {
            FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
            HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) context.getExternalContext().getRequest();

        try {
            request.login(this.user.getName(), this.user.getPassword());
            LOGGER.info("Login the user");
            ret = "success";
//          this.user = userDAO.find(this.username, this.password);
        } catch (ServletException e) {
            // Handle unknown username/password in request.login().
            context.addMessage(null, new FacesMessage("Unknown login"));
        }
    }
    LOGGER.info(ret);
    return ret;
}
```

But when I want to print the UserPrincipal.getName after a login, then I get a NullpointerException when I call:

```
request.getUserPrincipal().getName();
```

So whats wrong with my code or my way to create a new UserPrincipal after a successful login?

Best

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The user principal is only available in the subsequent requests after login. You need to send a redirect after login to force the browser to create a new request.

```
ret = "success?faces-redirect=true";
```

When printing username in view, better use EL. The [`HttpServletRequest`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html) is in EL already available by `#{request}`.

```
<p>Welcome #{request.userPrincipal.name}!</p>
```

or just the shortcut

```
<p>Welcome #{request.remoteUser}!</p>
```

Comment: when I do ret = "success?faces-redirect=true"; my navigation rule does not work. JSF does not redirect to success page

Comment: Also it seems that the login method does not create a new Principal. The UserPrincipal is also a null object when I want to print it in my login method after request.login

Comment: Oh you're still using old fashioned XML navigation rules? Put a `<redirect/>` in there, or just replace all those navigation rules by implicit navigation like `"viewId"` as in `"viewId?faces-redirect=true"`.

Comment: Yes thats right I use XML navigation rules? What is the better way? :) But the problem with the UserPrincipal is still there? Also when I want to print out the UserPrincipial in the Login method..